# Royal Enfield Classic 350, Clutch is not disengaging

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, enfield-classic, royal-enfield

I own a classic 350 which has done 5000 Kms. Recently my clutch cable broke and I tried replacing it with a new one (which I had done once before), but now the clutch lever seems stuck and it's not getting pulled back completely in order to be hooked to the cable. Also when I put the bike in gear and I pull the lever the clutch is not disengaging.
Has anyone experienced this issue? Is it a serious one? Please advise, I'm worried.

P.S: I contacted the service. They told me they will be coming to check the problem.

Comment: Without the cable, the clutch lever should be free to move back and forward without a problem. Check that nothing is blocking the movement, and lubricate the bushing on the lever.

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Comment: The clutch lever of royal enfield is extremely tight. I had to use a plier to loosen